# Newton's method with the second derivative included

Tags: newton-raphson

The usual formulation of Newton's method goes like -

$f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)f'(a)$

As $x$ is a root of $f$, $f(x) = 0$

And so -

$x = a - \frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}$

I was wondering if there was any way to include the second derivative too.

$f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)f'(a) + \frac{(x-a)^2f''(a)}{2}$

There is no obvious way to isolate $x$ here. Can we formulate some kind of iterative technique to make use of the above formula for find the root?

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Halley method

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks